# How to draw music note nicely on the stave with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have music note showed nicely on the Android app by drawing it from scratch instead of having to load an image file. Image file can make the image blurred. But it is complicated to draw music note by jetpack compose Kotlin code.

I've used below code to draw an arbitrary music note on the stave:

```
@Composable
fun MusicNoteC(
    lineHeight: Float,
    nodeWidth: Dp,
    noteX: Float,
    middleLineY: Float,
    noteHeadSize: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Canvas(modifier = modifier) {
        // Draw stave lines
        (0..4).forEach { y ->
            drawLine(
                color = Color.Black,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = y * lineHeight),
                end = Offset(x = nodeWidth.toPx(), y = y * lineHeight)
            )
        }

        // Draw note head
        drawOval(
            color = Color.Black,
            topLeft = Offset(x = noteX, y = middleLineY),
            size = Size(width = noteHeadSize, height = noteHeadSize)
        )

        // Draw stem
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            start = Offset(x = noteX + noteHeadSize / 2, y = middleLineY + noteHeadSize),
            end = Offset(x = noteX + noteHeadSize / 2, y = middleLineY + noteHeadSize * 2)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyMusicScreen() {
    val noteSpacing = 20f // Adjust as needed
    val notePosition = 3 // This note is the third in the sequence
    val noteX = noteSpacing * (notePosition - 1) // Assuming notePosition starts from 1

    val staveHeight = 100f // Example value
    val numLines = 5 // Standard number of stave lines
    val lineSpacing = 10f // Adjust as needed

    val middleLineY = staveHeight / 2f - (lineSpacing * (numLines - 1) / 2f)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        MusicNoteC(
            lineHeight = 10f,
            nodeWidth = 10.dp,
            noteX = noteX,
            middleLineY = middleLineY,
            noteHeadSize = 15f,
            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp) // Adjust size as desired
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ABCTheme {
        MyMusicScreen()
    }
}
```

But the output is NOT as expected:
[image]

I expect the note should be like this:
[image]

Comment: This seems more like an art and geometry question than programming, maybe? Like can you see that the width and height of the eclipse should not be equal?